# Need last value per Year and previous value if null for year

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have employees that change rates each year, sometimes several times in a year.  Trying to find last rate for year and if there was not rate changes for the year, then to pull the value for the previous year.  I have gotten the last record for the year, but having trouble using previous value for year that did not have a change.  Ideally I will have a result for each year.  But in saying that, I realize that could get out of control quickly.  So if there is a rate for 2008 and 2010, but not for 2009, I need 2008's rate to show up for 2009.   Using SQL Server 2008 R2
Considered doing a Cross or outer Apply with a Calendar, but I keep getting turned around.
I have already created the calendar, using Todd Fifield post and just adding in Yr with Year value.
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/70482/

This is what I have so far

```
with YrHist as
(
select h.HRCo, h.HRRef, h.EffectiveDate, YEAR(h.EffectiveDate) as EffectiveYr,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0,h.EffectiveDate),0) as EffMth, h.Type, h.NewSalary, h.OldSalary

from HRSH h
        left outer join PREHName p on h.HRCo=p.PRCo and h.HRRef=p.Employee
)

select distinct ROW_NUMBER() over(Order By tt.HRCo,tt.HRRef,tt.EffectiveYr) as RowID,
tt.HRCo, tt.HRRef,tt.EffMth, tt.EffectiveYr, tt.EffectiveDate, tt.Type, tt.NewSalary as MaxRateForYr, tt.OldSalary

from YrHist as tt

        inner join
            (select HRCo, HRRef, EffectiveYr, MAX(EffectiveDate) as MaxEffDate
            from YrHist
            Group By HRCo, HRRef, EffectiveYr) as m on tt.EffectiveYr=m.EffectiveYr and tt.EffectiveDate=m.MaxEffDate and tt.HRCo=m.HRCo and tt.HRRef=m.HRRef
```

[Example of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaOl2.png)

Comment: Wondering if Union All Join with Calendar and using COALESCE might get what I am looking for.

Comment: Ended up changing tables; instead of looking at table that kept salary changes, I used table for check history and used max date for each year.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up changing tables; instead of looking at table that kept salary changes, I used table for check history and used max date for each year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example and solve your problem

Assume you have a calendar table which includes all years

```
create table #cal (Yr int)
insert into #cal values (2010), (2011), (2012), (2013), (2014), (2015), (2016)
```

and assume this is the table you have the rates for each year

```
with x as (
  select 1 AS ID, 2010 AS Y, 58 AS Rate
  union
  select 2, 2011, 48
  union
  select 3, 2013, 38
  union
  select 4, 2013, 59
  union
  select 5, 2014, 68
  union
  select 6, 2014, 78
  union
  select 7, 2014, 56
  union
  select 8, 2016, 45
)
select * into #t from x
```

Then this query will give you the result you are looking for

```
select Yr
, isnull(max(cc.Rate), (select top 1 Rate from #t where Y < Yr order by ID desc)) Rate
from #cal
    left join #t ot on #cal.Yr = ot.Y
    outer apply (select top 1 ID, Rate from #t where Y = ot.Y order by ID desc) AS cc
group by #cal.Yr
```

**Result**

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ Yr   ║ Rate ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2010 ║ 58   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2011 ║ 48   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2012 ║ 48   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2013 ║ 59   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2014 ║ 56   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2015 ║ 56   ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ 2016 ║ 45   ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Not sure this would work for my case.  If I were just running for one employee, that would work, but I need this for all employees, based on their rates for each year.

Comment: I'll try to apply this on your query when I get a chance